# create a copy of backbone model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, copy

I want to create a copy of a backbone model.

In javascript, the objects are passed by reference. so if i have a backbone model model1 and another as model2 then if i write

```
model2 = model1
```

then model2 also refer to same model as model1. Any changes i make in model2 or model1 will reflect in both models.

How can i achieve a case, where model2 is exact copy of model1 but do not refer to same model. So changes made in each model remain with that particular model only .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [clone](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-clone) method

```
var model2 = model1.clone();
```

also use can use [$.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) that allows you to simply copy object properties from one to another